# I have issue with SPO – Ribbon Custom Action

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon

In “ribbon custom action” in SharePoint Online I want to invoke JavaScript code direct once click on the ribbon button rather than redirect to any aspx page (~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx).
But whenever I add JavaScript code in Elements.xml within CommandAction (see xml code below) :

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_Ribbon1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="javascript: alert('Hello');"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
```

Deployment doesn’t work, and generates this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step ‘Install app for SharePoint’: There
>   where errors when validating the App Package.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your CommandUIExtension should look like below:

```
    <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
                            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.Controls._children">
                                    <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.RibbonTest"
                                            Command="Notify"
                                            Sequence="0"                                         
                                            Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png"
                                            Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png"
                                            Description="Uses the notification area to display a message."
                                            LabelText="Notify hello"
                                            TemplateAlias="o1"/>
                                </CommandUIDefinition>
                            </CommandUIDefinitions>
                            <CommandUIHandlers>
                               <CommandUIHandler Command="Notify"
                                    CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(\'Hello stackoverflow\');" />
                            </CommandUIHandlers>
                           </CommandUIExtension>
```

Comment: Hi, The code shown by you is not working at my end. Do I need to do some extra stuffs?

Comment: Can you show the code you writing

Comment: You can find my code here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0848204165d715da7c30acf136e23394